# Date validation in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to validate ddmmmyyyy and dd-mmm-yyyy date formats using single regex. Please provide solution if anyone have idea

Answer (score 4):

There are two steps to producing a regex like that:

1. Learn regular expressions.
2. Use your knowledge to write the regex, and ask Stack Overflow if you have problems.

If you want to learn regular expressions then check out [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) - it's the best site out there. It even has a section on [JavaScript-specific regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html).

If you don't want to learn, then go away and stop wasting people's time.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dateFormat = /^(\d{4})-?(\d{2})-?(\d{2})$/
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
var match = myString.match(dateFormat);
if (match) {
  var year = +match[1], month, day;
  var field2 = +match[2], field3 = +match[3];
  var monthFirst = true; 
  if (field2 > 12 && field3 <= 12) {
    monthFirst = false;
  } else if (field2 <= 12 && field3 <= 12) {
    var systemDateFormat = "" + new Date(1970, 5, 13);
    monthFirst = systemDateFormat.indexOf("13") > systemDateFormat.indexOf("5");
  }
  if (monthFirst) {
    month = field2;
    day = field3;
  } else {
    month = field3;
    day = field2;
  }

  doSomethingWith(year, month, day);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you do any research? Assuming “mmm” are letters:

```
/^[0-9]{2}-?[a-zA-Z]{3}-?[0-9]{4}$/
```